# Ignore undefined behaviour of a library

Tags: c++, multithreading, undefined-behavior

i am currently developing a plugin system in cpp which uses dynamic libraries as plugins, running in their own respective threads. 
We have some external symbols to start and configure the libraries, which basically do their independent work. 
Those plugins run independent of each other, so if one crashes we do not want the others to stop and just keep working.

So far catching exceptions is no problem, but once i get undefined behaviour it causes the whole system to stop (obviously) though i want the error to be contained within these plugins.

Is there a way to implement this in cpp?
Thanks in advance.

(The word plugin may not be the right choice, but my english skills aren't that good. Feel free to edit.)

Comment: How are you planning on detecting undefined behavior? By its very definition it is undefined what it will do. You might be lucky and find some common pattern doing lots of testing, but even that is not guaranteed to be 100% reliable. (Your statement that it *"obviously"* stops the entire system is just a case of luck - undefined behavior can cause a ton of other things to occur)

Comment: Perhaps running as threads is ill-advised than. If they are part of your system's process, their UB will naturally affect you. How about spawning them as their own processes? Granted, now you need IPC to communicate, but a plugin failure won't crash your whole app.

Comment: I agree with @StoryTeller. you cannot catch undefined behaviour before it takes place. And when it does it's already too late. Running into threads naturally affect your process, and if something goes wrong in any of the process threads, then you process might be easily crashed by the OS or affected in any way UB can. If your process has to stay alive no matter what, and you are running "arbitrary code" into the plugins then I would go for running each plugin in a separate process.